# how to get location of div and highlight it

Tags: javascript, jquery

Like stackOverFlow ,after click the message box,the page jump to my question,locate and highlight the answer .

i want to implement it with  both  `javascript` and `jquery` .

Comment: you can use function focus to query: http://api.jquery.com/focus/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see [jquery ui's highlight effect](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Highlight) for highlighting the element

for scrolling to the element you can do:

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#elementtoScrollToID").offset().top
}, 2000);
```